# Custom Windows Azure Pack

Tags: azure-pack

I hope someone can help me on code the below.

At this moment I have a little problem with Windows Azure Pack, I want to custom the MgmtSvc-AuthSite and MgmtSvc-TenantSite to change the text, but for example with Chrome/Firefox the code I can see in HTML for example:

```
<div class="kt-introduction">
<h1>Unlimited Possibilities</h1>
<div class="kt-offering-value">
    <span>The future of cloud computing is @ your fingertips!</span>
    <ul>
        <li>Rich and powerful services</li>
        <li>Effortless management experience</li>
        <li>Open and flexible plataform</li>
        <li>Quickly build, deploy and manage applications across a global network</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but when I want to change the text of this, I only see this:

```
@using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Server.CommonPortalStrings;
<div class="kt-hero">
    <img src="/Content/Images/hero.png" alt="Hero"/>
</div>

<div class="kt-main-content-area">
    <div class="kt-introduction">
    <h1>@TenantPortalControllerResources.UnlimitedPossibilities</h1>
        <div class="kt-offering-value">
      <span>@TenantPortalControllerResources.CloudComputingWelcomeMessage</span>
        <ul>
            <li>@TenantPortalControllerResources.CloudServicesBenefits</li>
            <li>@TenantPortalControllerResources.CloudManagementWelcomeMessage</li>
            <li>@TenantPortalControllerResources.FlexiblePlatformBenefit</li>
            <li>@TenantPortalControllerResources.DeployApplicationQuickly</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

so... I have for many hours trying to find the source to change the code, but I failed... in MSDN I think with the command for powershell

```
Unprotect-MgmtSvcConfiguration -namespace AuthSite
Unprotect-MgmtSvcConfiguration -namespace TenantSite
```

but it does not work, so i'm out of ideas !...

Answer (score 0):

**I can understand your problem, changing the HTML will not change the content directly as the site is compiled and has very limited options to theme. There is a really good documentation on how to theme your Customer Azure Pack Portal.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528500.aspx

I use Azure Pack in side my company to host internal websites, **I use a landing page to bring the users and show information about the service and give them a link to the Management Portal.** I never share the management portal link, I only share the landing page link as users will start seeing the landing page and understand what needs to be done when they click on the link.

I got this from your text :),

I have something similar as well on the Landing page.

Hope the answer help, 
**Happy to Help -Yours truly, CB**